# Two different fonts in form submit button using font awesome

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, grails, font-awesome, gsp

I'm in in the process of modifying grails scaffolding templates and I would like to utilize font awesome icons for my buttons. An example of how I'm doing this is in the g:link tag below. I'm not sure how to emulate this with the form submit buttons. Appreciate any help!

```
    <g:form resource="\${this.${propertyName}}" method="DELETE">
            <fieldset class="buttons">
                <g:link class="" action="edit" resource="\${this.${propertyName}}"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa-lg">&nbsp;</i><g:message code="default.button.edit.label" default="Edit" /></g:link>
                <input class="" type="submit" value="\${message(code: 'default.button.delete.label', default: 'Delete')}" onclick="return confirm('\${message(code: 'default.button.delete.confirm.message', default: 'Are you sure?')}');" />
            </fieldset>
        </g:form>
```

The attached screen shot shows what it looks like now.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4IE9B.jpg)

Generated html:

```
    <form action="/fruits/delete/15" method="post" ><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE" id="_method" />
            <fieldset class="buttons">
                <a href="/fruits/edit/15" class=""><i class="fa fa-pencil fa-lg">&nbsp;</i>Edit</a>
                <input class="" type="submit" value="Delete" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?');" />
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: its a little tricky, you need to create a css element that the link resides in, then make the link transparent and scale a little further across than where it started from and transparent borders background.

Answer (score 0):

I found using html forms (vs g:form) easier to style when using icons. Resulting in something like:

`<form id="delete_id" action="${createLink(action: 'delete_method')}" method="get">
    <button  class="some_layout"type="submit"}>
      <i class="fa fa-pencil fa-lg">
      </i>&nbsp;Edit
    </button>
</form>`